# MySQLi_stmt::get_result()

Tags: prepared-statement, mysqlnd

I have a php app that is working perfectly offline (Windows). However, when I host it, I get a n error;Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result(). I know get_result() requires mysqlnd driver to work.
I have noted that several web hosts using linux servers don't have mysqlnd driver installed. Why is it too hard for them to install the driver?
Can someone please recommend a web host that supports it, or another way to solve this without re-writting the code? I know I can use bind_results() instead of get_results(), and I will use that in the future. But using it in the current app will involve rewritting too much code.
Thanks.

Comment: some useful links: [mySQLi prepared statement unable to get_result()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10466530/992406) and [Instal mysqlnd in a hosted website](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13728365/992406)

Comment: Thanks for the links @houssam. What I am getting is that several if not all PHP hosting servers don't have mysqlnd. I would really like to know why this is so.

Comment: you are welcome; I really have no direct answer to your question; I think that the only one who have the answer is the hosting companies themselves; try to contact them. Also; I recommend you edit your question with best title and add popular tag 'php' to ensure that your question will be seen by large number of people here or you can delete it and start a new question.